# Question regarding pointers and parameters, from Chapter Seven Exercises, in "Learn C on the Mac, Second Edition"

Tags: c, pointers, parameters

The reason for this posting is because I'm having difficulty understanding a couple of questions in the "Chapter Seven Exercises", from "Learn C on the Mac, Second Edition".

Part a:

```
//  the following code is part a, of question 1
void add_one(int *my_var);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    int num, i;
    
    num = 5;
    
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        add_one(&num);
//        printf("Num equals: %d\n", num);
    }
    
    printf("Final value is %d.\n", num);
    
    return 0;
}

void add_one(int *my_var)
{
    (*my_var) ++;
}
```

Part b:

```
//  the following code is part b, of question 1
int g_number;
int multiply_it(int my_var);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    int i, g_number = 2;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        g_number *= multiply_it(g_number);
//        printf("Global number equals: %d\n", g_number);
    }
    
    printf("Final value is %d.\n", g_number);
    
    return 0;
}

int multiply_it(int my_var) {
    return (my_var * g_number);
}
```

Part c:

```
//  the following code is part c, of question 1

int g_number;
int double_it(int my_var);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    int i;
    
    g_number = 1;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        g_number *= double_it(g_number);
    }
    
    printf("Final value is %d.\n", g_number);
    
    return 0;
}

int double_it(int my_var) {
    return 2 * my_var;
}
```

In the back of the book, they give the final value, for part b, as "512"; for part c, as "1024".

I understand how they arrived at the answer, for part a, but I'm having difficulty understanding the answers they got for parts b and c.

The three different parts are presented, in the textbook, as code fragments, but part of the problem is each have their own main(). I'm not sure why it's presented this way, but I've tried commenting out the other main() declaration lines (except for the code within them).

When I tried combining parts a and b, part a would output the correct answer (25), but part b would output a value of "0". So, I didn't even try part c, yet. Because part c doubles part b, I'm assuming I could figure out part c, if I could figure out part b.

Is there someone who could help me understand this, or point me in the direction of where I could understand the answer?

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Comment: Are you sure `g_number` is a local variable in part b?

Comment: I think `g_number` is suppose to be a global variable because it's declared outside a function. Part of what's learned in the chapter is global variables, so I think that's what they're testing you on, there.

Comment: In your given code its a global __and__ local in `main` though.

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running the *exact* code you posted (with the addition of the missing `#include <stdio.h>`)?  It doesn't do what you claim.  For example, Part b prints `0`.

Comment: In, both, parts b and c, it's declared as a global, then used in `main`. I'm not knowledgable enough to explain why the authors did that. I'm just copying the code way it is from the book, and trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yes. When running on Xcode, I have the header file, there. I just didn't put it, here. And, I said when I run the code, part "b" outputs "0". Look at the third-to-last paragraph, my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, global integer variables are initialized to 0 on its declaration.
So, part b in your code, `int g_number;` will be set to 0.

Second, `g_number` in function `multiply_it()` refers to the global variable which is 0. As a result, it'll return 0 since `myvar * 0` is always 0.

```
int multiply_it(int my_var) {
    return (my_var * g_number);
}
```

My guess is that your local variable `g_number` should NOT be declared. Instead, global variable should be assigned to 2.

This should be

```
int i, g_number = 2;
```

like this

```
int i;
g_number = 2;
```

and it prints 512 as expected.

Comment: Thank you! That worked! However, when I run part "c", it outputs "0". Why would that be?

Comment: For part c you would get 1024 if you had `g_number = double_it(g_number);` but with `*=` as written in the question it overflows the integer which is undefined behavior. Not sure if either or both of the issues you had are from transcribing the code from the book incorrectly or if the book itself is incorrect.

Comment: What I, also, noticed is if I used a semi-colon, on the line declaring the `i` variable, instead of a comma, to separate the declaration from the assignment, it worked with the same effect, as if the assignment statement was on a different line (I guess that's the compiler's attitude toward whitespace! LOL!). Still, however, I need help trying to figure out why part "c" still outputs "0". If you could, I'd appreciate your help with that. Thanks!

Comment: It is nothing to do with whitespace and everything to do with the syntax of the language. `int i, g_number = 2;` declares two variables, the first uninitialized and the second with a value of 2. `int i; g_number = 2;` declares a single uninitialized variable and assigns the value of 2 to a variable that must have been previously declared.

Comment: Retired Ninja: I transcribed it wrong! Thanks for pointing that out, and helping me! Now, it works!

Comment: Retired Ninja: what a I meant about whitespace was when you separate the variable declaration, from assignment statement, with a semi-colon, the compiler treats it as if it was on the same line. Keeping the declaration and assignment statement on separate lines is for the benefit of humans, not compilers. Do I have that wrong?

Comment: For the most part whitespace is for human readability. The compiler doesn't care, except for the few very specific cases where it does. The only one I can think of at the moment is the ``\`` that must be the last character of a line in a multi-line macro.